# Expo (React Native) Android build crashes, runs ok on emulator and iOS

Tags: react-native, expo

Been working with Expo before, like 4 yrs ago, then swithed to pure RN to avoid weird issues, and here we go again.

Runs fine on emulator, but .apk builds made with `eas build` keep crashing, looks like there's no js linked to them. Same result after running `./gradlew assembleDebug` locally. Need help.
No issues with iOS.

expo-cli: 6.1.0
SDK 46

EAS build config:

```
    "development": {
      "channel": "development",
      "android": {
        "autoIncrement": "versionCode",
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
```

Logcat for that apk:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.`

Tried updating expo, Gradle to 7.1.2 from 7.0.4 (encountered a few threads where that hepled), multiple eas.json config variations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

First install `expo-build-properties` with `expo install`

`app.json` plugins  add

```
   "plugins": [

....

 [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33
          }
        }
      ],

....

]
```

Hopefully this is your issue if not please add more details to your question.

Comment: did not work for my case

Comment: Did you find an alternative solution?